# JSF ajax replace element on drop-down list selection

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with 2 columns, each of which is a drop-down list. I want it to:

1) the choices of the second drop-down list are populated based on the option selected in the first drop-down list

2) the second dropdown list is replaced by a text box if the first one is selected to "Others".

Below is my code:

```
<p:column style="vertical-align: bottom;" headerText="Type">
   <h:selectOneMenu id="problemTypeDropdown" value="#{problem.type}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.problemTypeList}"/>
            <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.updateDescriptionDropdownList}"
                    update="problemDescriptionDropdown, problemDescText" />
            <f:attribute name="item" value="#{problem}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
<p:column style="width: 200px; vertical-align: bottom;" headerText="Description">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="problemDescriptionDropdown"
                     value="#{problem.description}"
                     rendered="#{problem.type!='Other'}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.descriptionDropdownList}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:inputText id="problemDescText"
                 value="#{problem.description}"
                 rendered="#{problem.type=='Other'}"/>
</p:column>
```

Backing bean:

```
public void updateDescriptionDropdownList(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    ProblemItem di = (ProblemItem)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("item");

    if (di.getType().equals("Other"))
        return;
    descriptionDropdownList = getDescriptionList(di.getType());
}
```

It can populate the second list based on the selection of first list now, but the second list is not replaced by the text box if the first is "Other".

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to place h:selectOneMenu and p:inputText in a container/panel, and update the container after ajax event.

```
    <p:column style="vertical-align: bottom;" headerText="Type">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="problemTypeDropdown" value="#{problem.type}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.problemTypeList}"/>
                <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean.updateDescriptionDropdownList}"
                    update="problemDescPanel" />
                <f:attribute name="item" value="#{problem}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width: 200px; vertical-align: bottom;" headerText="Description">
        <h:panelGroup id="problemDescPanel">
            <h:selectOneMenu id="problemDescriptionDropdown"
                 value="#{problem.description}"
                 rendered="#{problem.type!='Other'}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.descriptionDropdownList}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <p:inputText id="problemDescText" rendered="#{problem.type=='Other'}"
                 value="#{problem.description}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:column>
```

Comment: There is an error: "Cannot find component with expression "tableId:0:problemDescPanel" referenced from "form:tabView:tableId:0:problemTypeDropdown". I changed the update path to the full path "form:tabView:tableId:0:problemTypeDropdown" but it stills show the same error message.

Comment: after the initial display, can you open the page source and look for the exact id of `problemDescPanel` on each row? afaik, this was the standard id convention of jsf and primefaces, but i might be wrong.
also, please try `form:tabView:tableId:#{rowIndex}:problemDescPanel` as full path for `update`.

Comment: I tried. This is the error: "Cannot find component with expression "form:tabView:tableId:0:problemDescPanel" referenced from "form:tabView:tableId:0:problemTypeDropdown"

Comment: sorry about overcomplicating things (a tribute and thanks to Balusc). it works as expected when used like this: `update="problemDescPanel"`

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. It also works if I put    `update="@parent:problemDescPanel"`.  

Now that it worked, I'd like to know the reason behind all this. Why didn't my solution work? 
And I'm still very curious about that error message, "Cannot find component with expression "form:tabView:tableId:0:problemDescPanel" referenced from "form:tabView:tableId:0:problemTypeDropdown".

Comment: you are welcome. well, i have used that id notation/syntax many times with mojarra 2.1.7 and richfaces 4.3.1, but i guess things got a little simpler with the new versions. the problem of your solution was this: component with id "problemDescText" was not rendered on the page initially. so when you try to update/rerender it, no component with that id is found and update fails. you need to update a component which is always rendered on the page ("problemDescPanel" in this case), and conditionally render the components nested in it.